# What's the correct way of doing a SlideAnimation?

Tags: android, android-animation

In a RelativeLayout, I added an ImageView with some margin set in LayoutParams:

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rlLayoutParams.topMargin = (int) convertDpToPixel(kMARGIN_HEADER);
    rlLayoutParams.leftMargin = (int) myMAGIC_MARGIN;
```

Now this ImageView is somewhere in the middle of the screen. I want to have it slide a few hundred pixels to its right, and stay there, so I applied the following TranslateAnimation:

```
private TranslateAnimation getAnimation(ImageView view, int displacement, int duration) {
    int[] view_pos = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(view_pos);
    TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(
            view_pos[0], 
            view_pos[0] + displacement,  
            view_pos[1],
            view_pos[1]);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    slide.setDuration(duration);
    return slide;
}
```

Immediately after applying this animation, the whole view is gone. I checked the value of view_pos[] in debug mode, they are fine (not all zeroes). If I make the `setFillAfter` to false, then the view will come back after animation duration (for obvious reasons). So where did it go?

I also tried the following:

```
    TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(
            view_pos[0], 
            view_pos[0], // don't do the + displacement,  
            view_pos[1],
            view_pos[1]);
```

I was expecting the view to stay where it is. But no, it was vanished as well, with a chance of coming back afterwards, depending on the value of `setFillAfter`.

I start to think I cannot apply TranslateAnimation if the view was placed by LayoutParams in a RelativeLayout. How should I achieve the goal of sliding the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters for TranslateAnimation are deltas not positions, so you just want:

`slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, displacement, 0, 0)`.

If you don't need to support Android <3.0 then use a Property Animation instead of a View Animation - see the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/overview.html) for more details.